# SCORM - A small course that just that measures start and end

Tags: scorm

I've got a problem with a very simple course built with HTML that uses SCORM.

The only thing I would like to communicate with SCORM is if the course have been started **doLMSInitialize()** and if it has been finished **doLMSFinish()**. I'm using the APIWrapper.js from http://scorm12.com/.

I have three HTML-files:

1. index.html with following code:

   ```
   <script language="text/javascript" src="jscript/APIWrapper.js"></script>
   </head>

   <BODY onLoad="doLMSInitialize();">

   <a href="page-2.html">Page 2</a>
   ```
2. page-2.html with following code:

   ```
   <script language="text/javascript" src="jscript/APIWrapper.js"></script>
   </head>

   <BODY>

   <a href="end.html">End</a>
   ```
3. end.html with following code:

   ```
   <script language="text/javascript" src="jscript/APIWrapper.js"></script>
   </head>

   <BODY onUnload="doLMSFinish()">

   COMPLETE
   ```

But when I exit the course on the first page the LMS says that I have completed the course. I dont what this to happen before I have reached the last page.

If it helps you can find the my files togehter with my imsmanifest.xml here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/775928/scorm12-course.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCORM API can only be initialized once, and needs to remain in place for the duration of your course. Navigating from index.html to page-2.html will end the API connection that had been initialized in index.html. The solution is to use a frameset or iframe, with the API connection maintained within the parent frame.

Looking at your example, I'd use the following setup:

- index.html -- should contain all the javascript (including `jscript/APIWrapper.js`), and an iframe for loading content pages. This page invokes `doLMSInitialize` onload.
- page-1.html -- Loads in index.html's iframe. Contains whatever content goes on page 1. Does *not* load `jscript/APIWrapper.js`.
- page-2.html -- Loads in index.html's iframe. Contains whatever content goes on page 2. Does *not* load `jscript/APIWrapper.js`.
- end.html -- Loads in index.html's iframe. Invokes `doLMSFinish` in the parent frame (index.html):

  ```
  <script>
  window.onload = parent.doLMSFinish;
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the course - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/775928/scorm12-course-2.zip with the instructions you gave me. But I still got the same problem, the LMS still reports that I have completed the course even if I exit on the first page. Maybe this report will give some insight on the problem: http://cloud.scorm.com/sc/guest/ViewDebugLog?logId=9324e32e-f5fc-45eb-a189-2787f196e2b6&courseTitle=Test

Comment: you have a typo in your HTML page: language="text/javascript" should type="text/javascript". Because of this typo, your SCORM code is not being used at all (the script element is invalid, so the script never loads). Therefore the LMS is assuming the course is finished because there is no communication coming from the course.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the typo. Now the log looks different and LMSinitialize seems to work: http://cloud.scorm.com/sc/guest/ViewDebugLog?logId=551bd5ff-9344-4a76-b9bc-246fecab6b31&courseTitle=Test. But still the it says that the course is completed when you exit before the end. Maybe it has something to do with the following line: [09:04:39.723] Missing mastery score or raw score, setting to completed

Comment: Needed to set a cmi.core.lesson_status value!